# How can I compare each line of two .text files with same name located in two different folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am in the process of learning python. Please advice if my question does not fit with the format. I would like to compare ever single lines of two txt files located in two different folders. The file name is same in both the folder. So far I have written this much of code. I would like to request somebody to help me further on this code. The last two for loops is where my confusion is, I do not know how to compare each line of two files over there.

```
import os

dir1 ="C:/Users/Desktop/abc1-18/"  
dir2 ="C:/Users/Desktop/cde1-18/"

for files in os.listdir(dir1):
    file_name1 = os.path.join(dir1,files)
    if files in os.listdir(dir2):
        file_name2 = os.path.join(dir2,files)

        with open(file_name1, "r") as fi:
          with open(file_name2,"r") as Ri:

            for line1 in fi:
                for line2 in Ri:
                    if line1==line2:
                        print "something"
```

Comment: fix indentation and 2) it's the classic: you've reached the end of file issue.

Comment: I fixed the indentation. No, this is not the duplicate of the reffered links. In this case, I would like to compare each and every line with between two txt files

Comment: you didn't fix the indentation, and it's a duplicate of a classic: `Ri` is "empty" after one iteration. So your test cannot work. Either rewind or store the inner lines in a list, or best, in a `set`

Comment: Would you please help me understand more where I didnot fix the indentation and Ri being empty? Trust me, I am just learning python so some of these terms are hard to understand. I did fix the indentation of the entire code on my side.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that `Ri` handle is exhausted in the inner loop after one iteration of the outer loop, so you have to store the lines, I'd suggest a `set` for faster lookup:

```
with open(file_name1, "r") as fi:
  with open(file_name2,"r") as Ri:
    lines2 = set(Ri)
    for line1 in fi:
        if line1 in lines2:
             print "something"
```

that's way faster because of `set` and ... it works because the second file is read only once.

Aside, your outer loop could benefit from the same treatment. Change

```
for files in os.listdir(dir1):
    file_name1 = os.path.join(dir1,files)
    if files in os.listdir(dir2):
        file_name2 = os.path.join(dir2,files)
```

to

```
file2_dir = set(os.listdir(dir2))
for files in os.listdir(dir1):
    file_name1 = os.path.join(dir1,files)
    if file_name1 in file2_dir:
        file_name2 = os.path.join(dir2,files)
```

avoids to constantly scan the second directory, and putting the result in a set speeds up lookup.